# Why won't SQL Server optimize the UNIONs?

Tags: sql-server, performance, union, optimization, query-performance

Consider these queries ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20ebe/2/1)):

Query 1:

```
SELECT * INTO #TMP1 FROM Foo
UNION
SELECT * FROM Boo
UNION
SELECT * FROM Koo;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * INTO #TMP2 FROM Foo
UNION
SELECT * FROM Boo
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Koo;
```

**Note** that Koo does not overlap with Boo/Foo, so the end result is the same.  The question is why the first *UNION / UNION* combination is not merged into a single SORT operation?

Comment: `MERGE` join is more optimised than `SORT`. It has linear complexity and doesn't require a memory grant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The query optimizer does have n-ary operators, though the execution engine has rather fewer.  To illustrate, I'm going to use a simplified version of your tables - [(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68084).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    number
INTO foo
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE 
    number < 1000;

SELECT DISTINCT
    number
INTO boo
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE 
    number between 300 and 1005;

SELECT DISTINCT
    number
INTO koo
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE 
    number > 1006;

ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (number);
ALTER TABLE dbo.boo ADD PRIMARY KEY (number);
ALTER TABLE dbo.koo ADD PRIMARY KEY (number);
```

Given those tables and data, let's look at the input tree for a three-way `UNION` query:

```
SELECT f.number FROM dbo.foo AS f
UNION
SELECT b.number FROM dbo.boo AS b
UNION
SELECT k.number FROM dbo.koo AS k
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8605);

LogOp_Union
    OUTPUT(COL: Union1006 )
    CHILD(QCOL: [f].number)
    CHILD(QCOL: [b].number)
    CHILD(QCOL: [k].number)
    LogOp_Project
        LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.foo(alias TBL: f)
        AncOp_PrjList 
    LogOp_Project
        LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.boo(alias TBL: b)
        AncOp_PrjList 
    LogOp_Project
        LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.koo(alias TBL: k)
        AncOp_PrjList
```

The logical union operator has one output and three child inputs.  After cost-based optimization, the physical tree chosen is a merge union with three inputs:

```
SELECT f.number FROM dbo.foo AS f
UNION
SELECT b.number FROM dbo.boo AS b
UNION
SELECT k.number FROM dbo.koo AS k
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8607);

PhyOp_MergeUnion
    PhyOp_Range TBL: dbo.foo(alias TBL: f)(1) ASC
    PhyOp_Range TBL: dbo.boo(alias TBL: b)(1) ASC
    PhyOp_Range TBL: dbo.koo(alias TBL: k)(1) ASC
```

The optimizer's output is reworked into a form that the execution engine (without n-ary merge union) can handle:

[image: Merge union plan]

The post-optimization rewrite unfolds the n-ary `PhyOp_MergeUnion` into multiple Merge Union operators.  Notice how all the estimated cost remains associated with the 'original' union operator - the others have a zero cost estimate.

That the optimizer reasons about unions using n-ary operators provides one explanation for why it does not consider rewriting your first example to the same plan as the second example (the three-way union is a single tree node).

The second reason is there are no constraints to enforce the 'lack of overlap'.  Before constraints are in place, a union between `boo` and `koo` cannot be guaranteed not to produce duplicates, so we get a duplicate-removing plan (a Merge Union in this case):

```
SELECT b.number FROM dbo.boo AS b
UNION
SELECT k.number FROM dbo.koo AS k;
```

[image: boo/koo without constraints]

Adding the following constraints ensures the non-overlap condition cannot be violated without invalidating cached plans for the query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo WITH CHECK ADD CHECK (number < 1000);
ALTER TABLE dbo.boo WITH CHECK ADD CHECK (number BETWEEN 300 AND 1005);
ALTER TABLE dbo.koo WITH CHECK ADD CHECK (number > 1006);
```

Now it is safe for the optimizer to simply concatenate:

[image: boo/koo with constraints]

However, even with those constraints in place, the three-way union query still appears as three unions because the optimizer does not normally consider splitting n-ary operators to explore alternatives.  The n-ary operator thing is very useful in keeping the search space under control; breaking it apart would often be counter-productive given the optimizer's goal of finding a good plan quickly.

```
SELECT f.number FROM dbo.foo AS f
UNION
SELECT b.number FROM dbo.boo AS b
UNION
SELECT k.number FROM dbo.koo AS k;
```

[image: Merge union plan with constraints]

When written as a `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, an n-ary operator can no longer be used (the types do not match) so the tree has separate nodes:

```
SELECT f.number FROM dbo.foo AS f
UNION
SELECT b.number FROM dbo.boo AS b
UNION ALL
SELECT k.number FROM dbo.koo AS k
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8605);

LogOp_UnionAll
    OUTPUT(COL: Union1007 )
    CHILD(COL: Union1004 )
    CHILD(QCOL: [k].number)

    LogOp_Union
        OUTPUT(COL: Union1004 )
        CHILD(QCOL: [f].number)
        CHILD(QCOL: [b].number)

        LogOp_Project
            LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.foo(alias TBL: f)
            AncOp_PrjList 

        LogOp_Project
            LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.boo(alias TBL: b)
            AncOp_PrjList 

    LogOp_Project
        LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.koo(alias TBL: k)
        AncOp_PrjList
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server *does* have 3-way set operations; the CONCATENATION operator accepts *n* inputs. Given, for example, ten tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Test01 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80)); 
CREATE TABLE Test02 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test03 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test04 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test05 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test06 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test07 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test08 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test09 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE Test10 (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL, SomeAttribute VARCHAR(80));
```

and a query that unions everything to find any row in each table that has the same key:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM Test01 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test02 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test03 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test04 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test05 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test06 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test07 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test08 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test09 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test10
) AS Bunch
WHERE SomeKey = 39;
```

We'll see a query plan that gets the rows matching (with predicate push down in the TABLE SCAN operator) then concatenates all the results into the `SELECT` operator.

The reason that you don't get a plan merges then sorts is because it would be very slow, and the sort isn't necessary to implement the `UNION` operation. In your BOO, FOO, and KOO tables, you've declared a primary key. When the CLUSTERED INDEX SCAN accessor enumerates the rows, they are produced in the order of the underlying clustered index -- guaranteed. Concatenating two sets then sorting the result is much slower than using the MERGE JOIN operator, and the MJ operator can be used very readily since both sets are sorted and indexed.